# How does printf("%c%c",(char)'a',(char)'b'); actually work using variable arguments?

Tags: c

The statement `printf("%c%c",(char)'a',(char)'b');` prints "ab" onto the console, but why wouldn't the `char`s only take up 2 bytes of the arguments and then the `%c` require an `int`-sized argument and get confused? Or is there a minimum length for each of the variable arguments?

Comment: The print specifiers (c, d, f, etc) determine the length of the variable sent - see `man varargs`

Comment: "and get confused" _I_ got confused. Can you rephrase your question?